# D3.js - why mouseover and mouse out fired for each child elements?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I use d3.js to generate a svg circle with a text logo in mid of the circle.
Here is the svg result.

```
<g id="main">
  <circle r="114" fill="#F0E8D0"></circle>
  <text text-anchor="middle">The movie title</text>
</g>
```

[image]

Here is the d3.js

```
var circles = [{r: innerRadius}];
svg.append("g").attr("id","main");


svg.select("#main").selectAll("circle")
.data(circles).enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("r",function(d){return d.r})
.attr("fill","#F0E8D0");

svg.select("#main").append("text")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.text(function(){ return "The movie title";});
```

I also want to fire some animations when mouse hover and leave the circle.

```
svg.select("#main")
.on("mouseover",function(){
  //code for transition
}).on("mouseout",function(){
  //code for transition
})
```

So the problem is: 
  When mouse moves into the circle, the animation fires as expected, however, when mouse touches the text element, a mouseout event fires (mouse leaving the circle), followed by a mouseover event again (mouse entering the text element), which is not desirable.

It seems that  the animation callbacks will be called when mouse touches any child element of the "< g >" tag.

I do not want any animation happen when mouse touches the text element. How can I do it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can prevent the `text` element receiving mouse events (and thus a mouseout event triggering when you move the mouse over it) by setting `pointer-events` to `none`:

```
svg.select("#main").append("text")
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .attr("pointer-events", "none")
   .text(function(){ return "The movie title";});
```

You probably also want to set the events on the `circle` and not on the `g` element:

```
svg.select("#main").selectAll("circle")
   .data(circles).enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("r",function(d){return d.r})
   .attr("fill","#F0E8D0")
   .on("mouseover",function(){
     //code for transition
   })
   .on("mouseout",function(){
     //code for transition
   })
```

Answer (score 30):

An alternate solution is to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

`mouseenter` is similar to `mouseover` except that it is not triggered when the pointer (mouse) is moved from one of listener's (circle in this case) descendants' physical space (text in this case) to its own physical space.

Same reasoning for 'mouseleave'

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter
and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave

Comment: This is the correct and preferred answer, as the event does not fire multiple times for each element hovered inside the circle.