# Hide text elements and make text wrap in d3js app

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

So I have the following code to visualize a tree using the d3js library. My problem lies in the nodeEnter.append("text") portion for actually assigning the text value. For some reason it won't register that I've put a newline \n character in my text assignment because the text doesn't go to a newline in the rendering of the svg. Also, I want my text to be hidden normally and appear on mouseover; however, this doesn't work. Instead I managed to get the opposite functionality to work (hide on mouseover). Can somebody tell me how to get the mouseover funcitonality I want, and how to make the "\n" character actually send the remainder of the text to a newline?

TY

```
  nodeEnter.append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.name+"\n"+d.text; })
  .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
  .style("visibility","visible")
  .on("mouseenter", function(){d3.select(this)
    .style("visibility", "hidden")
    .transition()                      
    ;})
  .on("mouseleave", function(){d3.select(this)
    .style("visibility", "visible")
    .transition()                      
    ;});
```

(Basically wherever it has visibility set to visible I want it hidden, and wherever it is hidden I want it visible)

Comment: For the hide text functionality, simply swap the visibility attribute values you set (as you have the *opposite* of what you want).

Comment: That doesn't work. They start off as hidden, but when I mouse over it does nothing

Comment: Well elements that aren't displayed don't receive any events. You probably want to have the handler on the element that the text is attached to, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444070/d3-js-why-mouseover-and-mouse-out-fired-for-each-child-elements

Comment: ok yeah that worked ty :)